# Why is this correct for a divergent series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I recently read something and I can't wrap my head around it:

For a given divergent sequence $a_n$, we have the following property:
$$\lim \limits_{n \to\infty} |a_{n+p} - a_n| = 0$$
for a fixed value $p\in\mathbb{Q}$. To me it seems like this violates the cauchy sequence for convergent sequences, since we are considering a divergent series here. What is it that I am missing?

Comment: The point is that the you are taking sequences $p$-terms apart where to be Cauchy, you need not take two terms which are an arbitrary number of terms apart. Think about the harmonic series $a_n=\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i$.

Comment: A key point is that this isn’t true foe *any* divergent sequence…

Comment: If you take a non-constant $p$-periodic sequence, then it's divergent and $|a_{n+p}-a_n|$ not only tends to zero but *equals* zero for all $n$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, how would I argue about it bring not a general case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another nice example is $a_n = \sqrt{n}$.  Of course $a_n \to \infty$.  But for a fixed $p$ we have as $n \to \infty$
$$
\sqrt{n+p} - \sqrt{n} = \sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{p}{n}} - 1\right)
= \sqrt{n}\left(1+\frac{p}{2n}+O(n^{-2})-1\right)
= \frac{p}{2\sqrt{n}} + O(n^{-3/2})
$$
and therefore
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\big(a_{n+p}-a_n\big) = 0 .
$$

Comment: what is $O(n^{-2})$. It looks like the Landau notation. Sorry, if my question comes across as an idiotic one.

Comment: @yousafe007 Correct.  It means the rest of the series goes to zero at least as fast as $n^{-2}$.

Comment: If you don't like the big Oh notation, you can also show this using the mean value theorem: $\sqrt{n+p} - \sqrt{n} = p \left ( \frac{\sqrt{n+p} - \sqrt{n}}{p} \right )$, but the mean value theorem says the second term is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}}$ for some $c \in (n,n+p)$. This is bounded by $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$ and we see $|\sqrt{n+p} - \sqrt{n}| \leq \frac{p}{2 \sqrt{n}}$, which goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thank you for your clarification too, it helped me understand it a bit better. It's just that I had never used the Big O notation outside of my CS classes and that confused me a bit

Comment: Much easier than all the $O(\cdot)$ notation is to show $$0<\sqrt{n+p}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{p}{\sqrt{n+p}+\sqrt n}<\frac{p}{2\sqrt n}\to 0.$$

Comment: Thank you dear @ThomasAndrews for your far more succinct approach.

Answer (score 2):

Reason is, that in cauchy sequence definition de facto we have **uniform convergence** requirement with respect to $p$:
$$\forall \varepsilon \gt 0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \gt N, \forall p \in \mathbb{N}, |x_{n+p}-x_n|\lt \varepsilon$$

Here $N$ is **independent** from $p$.

> *We have one $N$ for all $p$*.

If we move $\forall p \in \mathbb{N}$ from it's place after condition for $N$ before it, then we lost uniform dependence for $N$ from $p$ i.e. cauchy sequence property and obtain
$$ \forall p \in \mathbb{N},\forall \varepsilon \gt 0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \gt N, |x_{n+p}-x_n|\lt \varepsilon$$
Now $N$ is **dependent** also on $p$, while before is not so.

> *For each $p$ we have corresponding $N$.*

Such sequence can be even divergent as is seen from example
$$x_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$$
for which for every $p$ holds $$x_{n+p}-x_n=\frac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n+p}\leqslant \frac{p}{n+1}\to 0$$

Answer (score -1):

**example**:

the increasing sequence
$$a_n:=\log(n)$$
is not bounded but
$$|a_{n+p}-a_n|=\log(n+p)-\log(n)=\log \frac{n+p}n=\log(1+\frac pn) \xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{}\\\lim_\limits{n\to  \infty}\log(1+\frac pn)=\log(1+\lim_\limits{n\to  \infty}\frac pn)=\log(1)=0\\$$
because the function $\log$ is continous at $1$.

---

Here is the **example** already posted by @GEdgar presented in the way @ThomasAndrews proposes:

the increasing sequence
$$a_n:=\sqrt{n}$$
is not bounded but
$$|a_{n+p}-a_n|=\sqrt{n+p}-\sqrt n=\frac{(\sqrt{n+p}-\sqrt n)(\sqrt{n+p}+\sqrt n)}{\sqrt{n+p}+\sqrt n}=\frac p {\sqrt{n+p}+\sqrt n}\le\frac p{2\sqrt{n}}\to0$$

---

Both are the specialization of the following **example**.

Is $f:(L,\infty) \mapsto \mathbb R$ a differentiable function and  $\lim_\limits{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$

and  $$a_n:=f(n)$$

then for $\xi_{n,p} \in (n,n+p)$

$$|a_{n+p}-a_n|=|f(n+p)-f(n)|=|f'(\xi_{n,p})|(n+p)-n|\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\\$$

by the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).

---

@zkutch proposes the follwoing **example**:

$$a_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac 1 k$$
We get

$$|a_{n+p}-a_n|= \sum_{k=n}^{n+p}\frac 1 k \le \frac{p+1}n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\\$$

This can be generalized in the following way:

$b_n$ is a sequence such that $b_n\to0$ and $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k$. Then for every $p$

$$|a_{n+p}-a_n|= \sum_{k=n}^{n+p}b_k=\sum_{k=0}^{p}b_{n+k}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{p}b_{n+k}=\sum_{k=0}^{p}\lim_{n\to\infty}b_{n+k}=\sum_{k=0}^{p}0=0$$

We know that the convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^na_k$ requires that $a_k$ is a null sequence, but that it is not sufficient for the existence of $\sum_{k=1}^na_k$ that $a_k$ is a null sequence. For all such null sequences $a_k$ where  $\sum_{k=1}^na_k$ does not converge, $\lim_{n\to \infty}|a_{n+p}-a_n|= 0$ for all $p$.

---

So we can construct examples  from null sequences and from functions with derivates that tend o $0$ if $x$ tends to infinity.